# Getting HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, Webservice PHP/NuSOAP on resultset with more than 1000 rows

Tags: php, web-services, resultset, nusoap

I handle a small webservice with two methods, everything is running great until the resulset returns more than 1000 rows.

I know I have to put some code here, but the project is very confidential, so I put only basic Nosuap object parameters.

```
$namespace = 'urn:server';
$server = new nusoap_server;
$server->configureWSDL('SOME_NAME', $namespace);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
$server->register('ws_consultar_reclamos',
array('fechas' => 'tns:fechas_array'),
array('return' => 'tns:reclamacion_array'),
$namespace,
'urn:server#ws_consultar_reclamos',
'rpc',
'encoded');
```

I repeat, everything runs great until the resultset has more than 1000 rows.

I'm using PHP with NuSOAP.

Is there any configuration that I have to change to accept a bigger resultset?

Please help me, I'm running out of time with this situation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked your server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you haven't done it yet, activate logging:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
log_errors = On
```

Have you tried to increase the memory limit in php.ini?

Comment: I was checking the logs and I found this: [Tue May 15 12:34:43 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.97] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84672482 bytes) in /var/www/...

Comment: That's what I was talking about in the previous comment. You should increase the memory limit. That will more likely fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

script may be timing out.  perhaps try settig the script timeout higher with

```
set_time_limit();
```

[set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

or modify it in your php.ini file.  its default to thirty so if you change it to 60 and all of a sudden 1000 rows works this is probably your issue.  5 minutes should be a safe bet, but good luck getting a user to wait that long.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I tried it before submit my post and it didn't work :(